# A vbscript to find windows version name and the service pack

Tags: vbscript

What's the simplest way to find out which version of `Windows`, and which service pack, is running on a computer with `VBScript`?

For example I'd want to know `Windows XP` and `Service Pack 3`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An easy way of doing this is to use the WMI class [Win32_OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which has the properties `ServicePackMajorVersion`, `ServicePackMinorVersion`, `Name` and `Version`. You can find samples here: [WMI Tasks: Operating Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394596%28VS.85%29.aspx)

The data you get back might not be in the exact format that you want though so you might need to have some kind of lookup table to make it look exactly right.