# How to determine windows version from a VB script?

Tags: windows, vbscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A vbscript to find windows version name and the service pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317794/a-vbscript-to-find-windows-version-name-and-the-service-pack)

My question says it all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Here is another version:

```
Set dtmConvertedDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set oss = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each os in oss
    Wscript.Echo "Boot Device: " & os.BootDevice
    Wscript.Echo "Build Number: " & os.BuildNumber
    Wscript.Echo "Build Type: " & os.BuildType
    Wscript.Echo "Caption: " & os.Caption
    Wscript.Echo "Code Set: " & os.CodeSet
    Wscript.Echo "Country Code: " & os.CountryCode
    Wscript.Echo "Debug: " & os.Debug
    Wscript.Echo "Encryption Level: " & os.EncryptionLevel
    dtmConvertedDate.Value = os.InstallDate
    dtmInstallDate = dtmConvertedDate.GetVarDate
    Wscript.Echo "Install Date: " & dtmInstallDate 
    Wscript.Echo "Licensed Users: " & os.NumberOfLicensedUsers
    Wscript.Echo "Organization: " & os.Organization
    Wscript.Echo "OS Language: " & os.OSLanguage
    Wscript.Echo "OS Product Suite: " & os.OSProductSuite
    Wscript.Echo "OS Type: " & os.OSType
    Wscript.Echo "Primary: " & os.Primary
    Wscript.Echo "Registered User: " & os.RegisteredUser
    Wscript.Echo "Serial Number: " & os.SerialNumber
    Wscript.Echo "Version: " & os.Version
Next
```

Results on:

> Microsoft Windows XP Professional
>
> Version: 5.1.2600

Comment: Both dtmConvertedDate and objWMIService are empty on my machine.

Answer (score 9):

From [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.scripting.wsh/msg/29cf28baa5eb095a?hl=en&):

```
' Copyright (c) 1997-1999 Microsoft Corporation 
'************************************************************************** * 
' 
' WMI Sample Script - Information about the OS (VBScript) 
' 
' This script demonstrates how to retrieve the info about the OS on the local machine from instances of 
' Win32_OperatingSystem. 
' 
'************************************************************************** * 
Set SystemSet = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem") 
for each System in SystemSet 
 WScript.Echo System.Caption 
 WScript.Echo System.Manufacturer 
 WScript.Echo System.BuildType 
 WScript.Echo " Version: " + System.Version 
 WScript.Echo " Locale: " + System.Locale 
 WScript.Echo " Windows Directory: " + System.WindowsDirectory 
 WScript.Echo " Total memory: " + System.TotalVisibleMemorySize + " bytes" 
 WScript.Echo " Serial Number: " + System.SerialNumber 
 Wscript.Echo "" 
next
```

The first message box gives me "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional".

Comment: On my machine (also Windows 7, BTW) the SystemSet object is empty...

Comment: The fact that the script I posted doesn't work means that somehow `GetObject("winmgmts:")` is not working for you. Googling [`winmgmts not installed`](http://www.google.com/search?q=winmgmts+not+installed) and looking through is your best bet. For instance, the first result talks about the `WMI service`; you should make sure this is running on your computer.