# VBS or Bat - Determine OS and Office Version

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, ms-office

Does anyone have a script that can determine the Windows OS and Office Version in the same script.

I have bits and pieces of the script but I can't seem to figure out how to incorporate both OS and Office Version in the script.  I started out in bat now I moved on to VBS as it seems to be able to provide more details however, if someone could just help out with logic in below I might be able to move forward.

I would like to know how I can setup a script like this.

```
If Windows 7 64bit & Office 2010
    do this
If Windows XP 32bit & Office 2007
    do this  
If Windows 7 & Office 2007
    do this
```

CODE FOR Detecting Windows Version  -- BAT SCRIPT

```
Echo Please wait.... detecting Windows OS version...
ver | find "2003" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto done

ver | find "XP" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_xp

ver | find "2000" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto done

ver | find "NT" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto done

if not exist %SystemRoot%\system32\systeminfo.exe goto warnthenexit

systeminfo | find "OS Name" > %TEMP%\osname.txt
FOR /F "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %%i IN (%TEMP%\osname.txt) DO set vers=%%i

echo %vers% | find "Windows 7" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_7

echo %vers% | find "Windows Server 2008" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto done

echo %vers% | find "Windows Vista" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_7

goto warnthenexit
```

Comment: For the OS:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317794/a-vbscript-to-find-windows-version-name-and-the-service-pack

Answer (score 3):

Although the the Office part is kind of slow, it does work.

Just include this inside a file with a name like **getversions.vbs**

On my computer, it printed:

**Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise**

**Microsoft Office 32-bit Components 2013, Version15**

```
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

    For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
        Wscript.Echo objOperatingSystem.Caption
    Next

    Set colSoft = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name Like 'Microsoft Office%'")

    If colSoft.Count = 0 Then
      wscript.echo "NO OFFFICE INSTALLED" 
    else
       For Each objItem In colSoft
          Wscript.echo objitem.caption & ", Version" & Left(objItem.Version, InStr(1,objItem.Version,".")-1)
          exit for
       Next
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.  I don't mind it being to slow as it will run at night time when users won't be logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Save this (VB Script) file as GetVersions.vbs.
It works 
Regards,
Shaun

```
Option Explicit ' Enforce variable declaration
    ' Declare objects
Dim oShell
Dim sOSVersion
Dim lOfficeVersion

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

On Error Resume Next
sOSVersion = oShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName")' Read the registry for the operating system version

lOfficeVersion = GetOfficeVersionNumber() ' Read the office version from the function

MsgBox "sOSVersion = " & sOSVersion & vbCrLf & "lOfficeVersion = " & lOfficeVersion

    Function GetOfficeVersionNumber()
        GetOfficeVersionNumber = ""  ' or you could use "Office not installed"
        Dim sTempValue
                    ' Read the Classes Root registry hive (it is a memory-only instance amalgamation of HKCU\Software\Classes and HKLM\Software\Classes registry keys) as it contains a source of information for the currently active Microsoft Office Excel application major version - it's quicker and easier to read the registry than the file version information after a location lookup). The trailing backslash on the line denotes that the @ or default registry key value is being queried.
        sTempValue = oShell.RegRead("HKCR\Excel.Application\CurVer\")
        If Len(sTempValue) > 2 Then GetOfficeVersionNumber = Replace(Right(sTempValue, 2), ".", "") ' Check the length of the value found and if greater than 2 digits then read the last two digits for the major Office version value
    End Function    ' GetOfficeVersionNumber
```