# VBScript to copy a file based on OS AND architecture

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have to copy a .cfg file to a specific location under the program files directory on my workplace servers.

Unfortunately this is not only OS dependent (2003/2008/2012) but also has to determine if the OS is 32 or 64 bit and copy to the 'Program Files (x86)' directory path if applicable.

My plan is to have the three different version of the the file on one server and have the script copy the relevant one to the right location (overwriting the existing file), but I've had pretty much zero exposure to vbscripting so I'm struggling big time!

Comment: What have you tried? is this running from one machine or on each? - [A vbscript to find windows version name and the service pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317794/a-vbscript-to-find-windows-version-name-and-the-service-pack) Follow the answer link to the `Win32_OperatingSystem` page and see the `OSArchitecture`/`Version` properties, there is an example @ the bottom. (You can use `InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem where primary=true")` and avoid the for loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMI is probably the best approach. Assuming that the script will be run on each target host you could do something like this:

```
srcFolder = "..."

Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

For Each os In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
  ver  = Left(os.Version, 3)
Next

Select Case ver
  Case "5.2" : src = fso.BuildPath(srcFolder, "w3003_foo.cfg")
  Case "6.0" : src = fso.BuildPath(srcFolder, "w2008_foo.cfg")
  Case "6.1" : src = fso.BuildPath(srcFolder, "w2008r2_foo.cfg")
  Case "6.2" : src = fso.BuildPath(srcFolder, "w2012_foo.cfg")
  Case Else  : WScript.Echo "Unsupported OS version: " & ver
               WScript.Quit
End Select

If sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%") = "AMD64" Then
  dst = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\some\foo.cfg")
Else
  dst = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles%\some\foo.cfg")
End If

fso.CopyFile src, dst
```

Comment: Thanks for that, seems like exactly what I need. I've put all my file names/directories in there but I'm getting an error:

Line: 7
Char: 10
Error: Expected identifier
Code: 800A03F2

This is referring to the 'In' command.

Comment: Looks like it should be `For Each os In`

Comment: @AlexK. Indeed it should. Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Comment: Right, I've fixed that and I'm now getting an 800A004C error at Line 25 char 1.

A quick Google tells me this is essentially an incorrect path. In my script I have "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\SolarWinds\SolarWinds Log Forwarder for Windows\LogForwarderSettings.cfg" If I stick that filepath in a run box it pops straight up but even if I edit the filename out of the script I get the same error. Checked my source folder too and can UNC to that.

Comment: Add some debugging code before `CopyFile`, something like `WScript.Echo src : WScript.Echo fso.FileExists(src) : WScript.Echo dst : WScript.Echo fso.FileExists(dst)`. Are you running the script with highest privileges?

Comment: Alright now I feel like I'm getting somewhere! Looks like the issue ties in with the architecture detection as the script is trying to copy to the Program Files folder and not the (x86) folder. Thought I'd give it a go on a 32 bit 2003 box and I get an error at line 9 char 3 "Onject doesn't support this property or method: 'os.OSArchitecture'. I'm wondering, is there a way to just have it to try and copy to both Program Files AND x86, and just supress any errors if the directory doesn't exist? Or is that too messy?

Comment: For Server 2003 and earlier it's probably safe to assume that the OS will always be 32-bit, so you could check `os.OSArchitecture` only for more recent versions. See updated answer.

Comment: 2003 now works! Thank you! Unfortunately I'm still having an issue where the script recognises that the server's an x64, but it's trying to copy the file to the Program Files, not the (x86) folder.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - "For Server 2003 and earlier it's probably safe to assume that the OS will always be 32-bit" - Incorrect assumption, as there is Windows Server 2003 x64 Edition.

Comment: @PanayotKarabakalov Yes, there is a 64-bit version of Server 2003, otherwise there wouldn't be anything to assume about the architecture. Its use is rather uncommon, though, so I maintain that with Server 2003 it's usually safe to assume a 32-bit version.

Comment: Unfortunately we do have a few 2003x64 boxes floating around so I'm thinking a solution would be to check if the Program Files (x86) directory exists, if it does, copy, if not copy to Program Files\filepath... How would I go about tdoing that?

Comment: In that case check `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` as @PanayotKarabakalov suggested (+1). See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

OS Version you can get with WMI (or from registry).

```
For Each os In GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
    ver = os.Version
Next
```

But for OS Architecture I'll suggest one of the next - 
WMI `Win32_Processor` or `Shell.Environment` (alot more fatser).

```
ver = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'").AddressWidth
If ver = 64 Then ...

ver = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("SYSTEM")("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
If ver = "AMD64" Then ...
```

Comment: OK I still have problems. If I use the first part of your solution, I get an error on 2K3 boxes that the OS is not recognised, and I don't understand how I would use the 2nd part in the context of the script. The one that Ansgar wrote is great in that it detects the OS but it falls over as it always tries to copy into Program Files regardless of the architecture. What I need is the first part of his script to detect the OS, followed by a 2nd part that tries to copy to both Program Files AND Prg Files (x86) and ignores if one directory path doesn't exist.

Comment: @user2068365 - "I don't understand how I would use the 2nd part in the context of the script" - see Ansgar updated answer.