# VBScript OS Prop

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

I´m creating a VBScript to get OS information (to workstations and servers), At this point I need a function that gives me the OS Edition ONLY, example

```
WScript.Echo "Operating System Edition: "  Standard
WScript.Echo "Operating System Edition: "  Enterprise
WScript.Echo "Operating System Edition: "  Web
WScript.Echo "Operating System Edition: "  Pro
WScript.Echo "Operating System Edition: "  Ultimate
```

and so on...

I try to get this information using the WMI Class Win32_OperatingSystem, but no property available that shows this information.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A vbscript to find windows version name and the service pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317794/a-vbscript-to-find-windows-version-name-and-the-service-pack)

Comment: SKU isn't version + servicepack..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `int`-property called `OpertingSystemSKU` in [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx). You would have to convert that int into OS edition. An updated list of the values can be found at [GetProductInfo @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358(v=vs.85).aspx).

Here's a convert-function. I just used the constant-names so you might want to clean it up:

```
function Get-OSSKU ([int]$int) {

    $SKU = @{
        0x00000006 = 'PRODUCT_BUSINESS'
        0x00000010 = 'PRODUCT_BUSINESS_N'
        0x00000012 = 'PRODUCT_CLUSTER_SERVER'
        0x00000040 = 'PRODUCT_CLUSTER_SERVER_V'
        0x00000065 = 'PRODUCT_CORE'
        0x00000063 = 'PRODUCT_CORE_COUNTRYSPECIFIC'
        0x00000062 = 'PRODUCT_CORE_N'
        0x00000064 = 'PRODUCT_CORE_SINGLELANGUAGE'
        0x00000050 = 'PRODUCT_DATACENTER_EVALUATION_SERVER'
        0x00000008 = 'PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER'
        0x0000000C = 'PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER_CORE'
        0x00000027 = 'PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER_CORE_V'
        0x00000025 = 'PRODUCT_DATACENTER_SERVER_V'
        0x00000079 = 'PRODUCT_EDUCATION'
        0x0000007A = 'PRODUCT_EDUCATION_N'
        0x00000004 = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE'
        0x00000046 = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_E'
        0x00000048 = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_EVALUATION'
        0x0000001B = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_N'
        0x00000054 = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_N_EVALUATION'
        0x0000007D = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S'
        0x00000081 = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S_EVALUATION'
        0x0000007E = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S_N'
        0x00000082 = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S_N_EVALUATION'
        0x0000000A = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER'
        0x0000000E = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE'
        0x00000029 = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE_V'
        0x0000000F = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_IA64'
        0x00000026 = 'PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_V'
        0x0000003C = 'PRODUCT_ESSENTIALBUSINESS_SERVER_ADDL'
        0x0000003E = 'PRODUCT_ESSENTIALBUSINESS_SERVER_ADDLSVC'
        0x0000003B = 'PRODUCT_ESSENTIALBUSINESS_SERVER_MGMT'
        0x0000003D = 'PRODUCT_ESSENTIALBUSINESS_SERVER_MGMTSVC'
        0x00000002 = 'PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC'
        0x00000043 = 'PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC_E'
        0x00000005 = 'PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC_N'
        0x00000003 = 'PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM'
        0x00000044 = 'PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM_E'
        0x0000001A = 'PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM_N'
        0x00000022 = 'PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM_SERVER'
        0x00000013 = 'PRODUCT_HOME_SERVER'
        0x0000002A = 'PRODUCT_HYPERV'
        0x0000007B = 'PRODUCT_IOTUAP'
        0x00000083 = 'PRODUCT_IOTUAPCOMMERCIAL'
        0x0000001E = 'PRODUCT_MEDIUMBUSINESS_SERVER_MANAGEMENT'
        0x00000020 = 'PRODUCT_MEDIUMBUSINESS_SERVER_MESSAGING'
        0x0000001F = 'PRODUCT_MEDIUMBUSINESS_SERVER_SECURITY'
        0x00000068 = 'PRODUCT_MOBILE_CORE'
        0x00000085 = 'PRODUCT_MOBILE_ENTERPRISE'
        0x0000004D = 'PRODUCT_MULTIPOINT_PREMIUM_SERVER'
        0x0000004C = 'PRODUCT_MULTIPOINT_STANDARD_SERVER'
        0x00000030 = 'PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL'
        0x00000045 = 'PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL_E'
        0x00000031 = 'PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL_N'
        0x00000067 = 'PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL_WMC'
        0x00000032 = 'PRODUCT_SB_SOLUTION_SERVER'
        0x00000036 = 'PRODUCT_SB_SOLUTION_SERVER_EM'
        0x00000033 = 'PRODUCT_SERVER_FOR_SB_SOLUTIONS'
        0x00000037 = 'PRODUCT_SERVER_FOR_SB_SOLUTIONS_EM'
        0x00000018 = 'PRODUCT_SERVER_FOR_SMALLBUSINESS'
        0x00000023 = 'PRODUCT_SERVER_FOR_SMALLBUSINESS_V'
        0x00000021 = 'PRODUCT_SERVER_FOUNDATION'
        0x00000009 = 'PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER'
        0x00000019 = 'PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER_PREMIUM'
        0x0000003F = 'PRODUCT_SMALLBUSINESS_SERVER_PREMIUM_CORE'
        0x00000038 = 'PRODUCT_SOLUTION_EMBEDDEDSERVER'
        0x0000004F = 'PRODUCT_STANDARD_EVALUATION_SERVER'
        0x00000007 = 'PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER'
        0x0000000D = 'PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE'
        0x00000028 = 'PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE_V'
        0x00000024 = 'PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_V'
        0x00000034 = 'PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_SOLUTIONS'
        0x00000035 = 'PRODUCT_STANDARD_SERVER_SOLUTIONS_CORE'
        0x0000000B = 'PRODUCT_STARTER'
        0x00000042 = 'PRODUCT_STARTER_E'
        0x0000002F = 'PRODUCT_STARTER_N'
        0x00000017 = 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_ENTERPRISE_SERVER'
        0x0000002E = 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE'
        0x00000014 = 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_EXPRESS_SERVER'
        0x0000002B = 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_EXPRESS_SERVER_CORE'
        0x00000060 = 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_STANDARD_EVALUATION_SERVER'
        0x00000015 = 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_STANDARD_SERVER'
        0x0000002C = 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE'
        0x0000005F = 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_WORKGROUP_EVALUATION_SERVER'
        0x00000016 = 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_WORKGROUP_SERVER'
        0x0000002D = 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_WORKGROUP_SERVER_CORE'
        0x00000001 = 'PRODUCT_ULTIMATE'
        0x00000047 = 'PRODUCT_ULTIMATE_E'
        0x0000001C = 'PRODUCT_ULTIMATE_N'
        0x00000000 = 'PRODUCT_UNDEFINED'
        0x00000011 = 'PRODUCT_WEB_SERVER'
        0x0000001D = 'PRODUCT_WEB_SERVER_CORE'
    }

    $sku[$int]

}
```

Demo:

```
$osSKU = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OperatingSystemSKU

"Computer has SKU $osSKU which is '$(Get-OSSKU $osSKU)'"
Computer has SKU 48 which is 'PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL'
```

**UPDATE**: How to use different solutions for different OSVersions:

```
$os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem

switch -Wildcard ($os.Version) {
    "5.*" {
        #2003 / 2003 R2
        $_.Caption.Split(",")[-1].Trim()
    }
    "6.*" {
        #2008+
        Get-OSSKU $os.OperatingSystemSKU
    }
    "10.*" {
        Get-OSSKU $os.OperatingSystemSKU
    }
    default { 
        #Fallback. Pre-2003 OS. Don't know how to handle
        $os.Caption
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was tagged with PowerShell so that's what I wrote, but if you need VBScript you could just convert it. Everything is available there too.

Comment: That s exactly what I was looking for... Thank you :)

Comment: I just found out that the "OperatingSystemSKU" does not exist Exist in Windows 2003, how to get the same information on Windows 2003? ANY Reg Entry?

Comment: Use the `Caption`-property in Win32_OperatingSystem. It should look something like `Microsoft Windows 2003 Standard Edition`.

Comment: Not Enough, I need the Real SKU, should be something like Standard, Web, Enterprise, Professional, Ultimate, etc...

Comment: Did you try Caption? I think it does say that. Just remove the first part of the string.

Comment: I need the SKU value, not the caption.Shoulld be something like Standard, Professional, Ultimate, etc...

Comment: You're not listening... I said you need to remove the first part of the string. Ex. Caption on a 2003 server i `Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Standard Edition`, so then we split on `,` and use the last part. Ex.. `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_operatingsystem | % { $_.Caption.Split(",")[-1].Trim() }` which will return `Standard Edition`

Comment: That Would work only in that scenario (Meaning you expect to have a "," to get the value), but not all OS Captions are like that, some show different captions depending of the OS version, CD Release, Licencing etc...

Comment: Well then you create a test per OS-Version and handle the Caption differently. I don't know of any other way to get the SKU in older OSes. SKU is something that was introduced With produkt key-based licensing. In the days of 2003 etc. the installation media decided which edition you got, but in 2008+ the number of editions increased a lot and the edition is decided by the product key you enter during installation (and you can upgrade editions after installation). This is only for OSes below 2008, so I don't believe you have to create many conditions and solutions... See update for example

Comment: switch statement is a nice touch, to do wildcard in VBScript is a bit tricky, but a desing a similar solution. Thank you all.

Comment: You can replace wildcards with `InStr`

Answer (score 0):

```
'Function Start
Function getOSVersion
    On Error Resume Next    
    Dim OSS, OS
    Set OSS = oWMI.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
    For Each OS in OSS
         getOSVersion = OS.Caption
    Next
   Set OSS = Nothing    
End Function
'Function End

'Call Function
Dim getOS
getOS = getOSVersion
WScript.Echo "OS VERSION is : " & getOS
```